# In helm-swoop minibuffer, insert text saved in registers

Tags: helm, minibuffer

This is my usecase:

1. Open `file1`
2. store the text in register `a` using `C-x r s a`
3. Go to another place, store the text in register `a` using `C-x r s b`
4. Go to file, store the text in register `a` using `C-x r s c`
5. Invoke `helm-swoop`
6. Insert the content of the registers `a`, `b`, `c` with `\|`    i.e. `(text_in_rega\|text_in_regb\|text_in_regc\)`
7. `M-i`
8. This will show me the `grep` like across files, I can use `C-c C-e` and edit multiple files at once and save them.
9. This is a big time saver in verilog.

Comment: One possible solution is adding an action on `helm-register` to invoke `helm-swoop`.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question is - "How do I insert text saved in registers, within the helm-swoop minibuffer" ?

Comment: Or - Is there a way, where I can write a small function to automate the steps - 5 & 6. I tried writing one like this... (defun test0 ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((ctext (concat "\(" (insert-register a 't) "\|" (insert-register b 't) "\|" (insert-register c 't))))) - but this is not working
  (message "Current Dir yank(ed). %s" ctext)
)

Answer (score 1):

```
;; STrip text properties - taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372722/print-only-text-discarding-text-properties

(defun strip-text-properties(txt)
  (set-text-properties 0 (length txt) nil txt)
      txt)

;;new function        
(defun swoop-test0 ()
    (interactive)
   (let ((ctext (concat "\\(\\_<" (strip-text-properties (get-register ?a)) "\\_>\\|\\_<"  (strip-text-properties (get-register ?b)) "\\_>\\)")))
    (helm-swoop :$query ctext )
   )
  )
```

I need to make it more clean by checking if the register is nil.